# SQL Query for counting number of orders per customer and Total Dollar amount

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables
`Order` with columns:

```
OrderID,OrderDate,CID,EmployeeID
```

And `OrderItem` with columns:

```
OrderID,ItemID,Quantity,SalePrice
```

I need to return the CustomerID(CID), number of orders per customer, and each customers total amount for all orders.

So far I have two separate queries. One gives me the count of customer orders....

```
SELECT CID, Count(Order.OrderID) AS TotalOrders
FROM [Order]
Where CID = CID 
GROUP BY CID
Order BY Count(Order.OrderID) DESC;
```

And the other gives me the total sales. I'm having trouble combining them...

```
SELECT CID, Sum(OrderItem.Quantity*OrderItem.SalePrice) AS TotalDollarAmount
FROM OrderItem, [Order]
WHERE OrderItem.OrderID = [Order].OrderID
GROUP BY CID
```

I'm doing this in Access 2010.

Comment: what's up with Where CID = CID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` in other SQL engines:

```
SELECT CID, 
       Count(DISTINCT O.OrderID) AS TotalOrders, 
       Sum(OI.Quantity*OI.SalePrice) AS TotalDollarAmount 
FROM [Order] O
INNER JOIN [OrderItem] OI
  ON O.OrderID = OI.OrderID
GROUP BY CID 
Order BY Count(DISTINCT O.OrderID) DESC
```

Which Access unfortunately does not support.  Instead you can first get the Order dollar amounts and then join them before figuring the order counts:

```
SELECT CID,
       COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS TotalOrders,
       SUM(OrderAmounts.DollarAmount) AS TotalDollarAmount
FROM [Orders]
INNER JOIN (SELECT OrderID, Sum(Quantity*SalePrice) AS DollarAmount 
      FROM OrderItems GROUP BY OrderID) AS OrderAmounts
  ON Orders.OrderID = OrderAmounts.OrderID
GROUP BY CID
ORDER BY Count(Orders.OrderID) DESC
```

If you need to include Customers that have orders with no items (unusual but possible), change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do a distinct count on CID as a customer can place more  than one order? Assuming that each order has a unique ID?

Comment: @MgMogaki `GROUP BY CID` accomplishes grouping the counts by customer (since CID is the customer's unique ID).

Answer (score 2):

Create a query which uses your 2 existing queries as subqueriers, and join the 2 subqueries on `CID`.  Define your `ORDER BY` in the parent query instead of in a subquery.

```
SELECT
    sub1.CID,
    sub1.TotalOrders,
    sub2.TotalDollarAmount
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CID,
            Count(Order.OrderID) AS TotalOrders
        FROM [Order]
        GROUP BY CID
    ) AS sub1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            CID,
            Sum(OrderItem.Quantity*OrderItem.SalePrice)
                AS TotalDollarAmount
        FROM OrderItem INNER JOIN [Order]
        ON OrderItem.OrderID = [Order].OrderID
        GROUP BY CID
    ) AS sub2
    ON sub1.CID = sub2.CID
ORDER BY sub1.TotalOrders DESC;
```