# SQL Query to count and calculate amount based on columns in different tables

Tags: sql

My Question:-

A list of customers who placed more than one order with MIP in the past. Write a SELECT statement that returns one row for each customer that has orders with these columns:

- The customer FirstName and EmailAddress columns
- A count of the number of orders placed by the customer
- The total amount for all orders placed by that customer  (from the table OrderItems)

My ERD:-
[image: ERD]

My problem:- I am completed stuck. No idea. This is an assignment question.
I tried it with count also but just a suggestion as to how to go about it would be appreciated. I need to calculate the total amount spent by these customers which is through a third table
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Query for counting number of orders per customer and Total Dollar amount](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808069/sql-query-for-counting-number-of-orders-per-customer-and-total-dollar-amount)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do an inner join on the customer and order table. Then group by on firstname and email address. Do a count on the no of orders and a sum on the amount.
If your tables were named Customer and Order, the sql statement would be like

```
SELECT 
    Customer.FirstName
    ,Customer.EmailAddress
    ,COUNT(Order.OrderId) AS OrdersPlaced
    ,SUM(Order.Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM 
    Customer
    INNER JOIN Order ON Customer.CustomerID = Order.CustomerID
GROUP BY
    Customer.FirstName
    ,Customer.EmailAddress
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, did not see your ERD earlier
 SELECT Customers.FirstName ,Customers.EmailAddress ,COUNT(Orders.OrderId) AS OrdersPlaced ,SUM(Orders.ShipAmount) AS TotalAmount FROM Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID GROUP BY Customers.FirstName ,Customers.EmailAddress

If you need the Tax amount included as well, you can change SUM(Orders.ShipAmount) to SUM(Orders.ShipAmount) + SUM(Orders.TaxAmount)

Comment: @Adish..Yes you are right and the problem is that I dont need the taxamount or the ShipAmount ..I need to calculate the TotalAmount from the OrderItems Table wherein TotalAmount = (ItemPrice -DiscountAmount )  * Quantity

Comment: and yes we just need those customers who have placed more than one order so I am trying to do that with a where clause

Comment: SELECT Customers.FirstName ,Customers.EmailAddress ,
COUNT(Orders.OrderId) AS OrdersPlaced 
FROM Customers INNER JOIN Orders 
ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID 
GROUP BY Customers.FirstName ,Customers.EmailAddress
HAVING COUNT (Orders.OrderID) >= 2 So this does work but I still need to calculate the total amount for all these orders placed.

Comment: SELECT Customers.FirstName ,Customers.EmailAddress , COUNT(Orders.OrderId) AS OrdersPlaced, SUM( (OrderItems.ItemPrice -OrderItems.DiscountAmount ) * OrderItems.Quantity ) TotalAmount FROM Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID INNER JOIN OrderItems ON Orders.OrderID = OrderItems.OrderID GROUP BY Customers.FirstName ,Customers.EmailAddress HAVING COUNT (Orders.OrderID) > 1 

You may need to need COALESCE if DiscountAmount in the OrderItems table is null. I am assuming ItemPrice will never be null. Note that I have changed >= 2 to > 1 in the where clause.

Comment: @Adish..works perfectly..according to the question it is returning the right answer ...but for some reason when I use it without the TotalAmount clause like the one query designed above it returned 5 entries and in this case it returned 9 ..dont know why it creating this problem but nonetheless  thank you for your answer works perfectly I will spend some more of my time on the problem..:)